# Simulate something like Crystal Reports in .NET

Tags: .net, wpf, crystal-reports, custom-controls, gdi

I need to simulate something like crystal reports in a WinForms .NET solution.

User will be able to modify margins, identify objets, double-click on them to see its properties, modify its coordinates, and then print the "model" associating some real objets to it.

[image]

What approach to take to realize all that?

For separate objects:
- Custom Controls (labels) ?
- Custom drawings (with click identification) ?

For technique fo the the working canvas, with marings?
- WPF UserControl?
- WinForms UserControl?

If I select custom Drawings, should I prefer WPF Drawing or GDI (more familiar)

Comment: Could you just use word documents and then merge data in using some form of "tags" like you've indicated there with []

Comment: And the reason you want to re-invent the wheel is ...?

Answer (score 0):

We used some RTF Printing/Editing component form the ComponentOne suite.
We created a GUI that is a like a simple RTF editor, and the user can add/format fixed text or dynamic field that will be compiled by our SW during the print.
These "dynamic fields" are handled in the RTF; they are simply "rtf text" that the user can't edit.

About why we reinvented the wheel, well, we need some more flexibility, and some more stability. We wanted to create something that can print even if MS Office is not installed. We wanted something more flexible/stable/supported/tailored_to_our_need than CrystalReport :-)